# Get text from div tag named with specific pattern

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I made an app to search for lyrics for songs on Spotify. The app gets all the lyrics from Genius.com. The problem is that they've changed their website and now the div tag containing all the lyrics is named in a weird name... Recently, it was named just `lyrics` but now it's like this: `Lyrics__Container-sc-1ynbvzw-2 jgQsqn` and I guess every div tag contains the "Lyrics__Container" keyword and the letters after it just changes. My line for getting lyrics looks like this:

```
page = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
lyrics = html.find('div', class_='lyrics').get_text()
```

Is there a way to get text from a div tag just by knowing that it start with "Lyrics__Container"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex with `class_` :

"As with any keyword argument, you can pass class_ a string, a regular expression, a function, or True:"
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Ex:

```
import re

lyrics = html.find('div', class_=re.compile(r'^Lyrics__Container')).get_text()
```